# Are there any FAA written test centers outside of the USA?

Tags: faa-knowledge-test

I'm Chinese and seeking to be a private pilot, but only have limited time.

I want to finish the FAA written test before I start flight training. Is there a list of international testing centers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked with PSI support. The answer is no. Only military bases and the USA have FAA written test centers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can find a list of international PSI testing center locations [here](https://www.gisci.org/Portals/0/PDF%27s/PSI%20International%20Locations.pdf).

Comment: Do these locations offer FAA tests? Not every PSI location does.

Comment: It seems outdated. I checked China, South Korea in https://faa.psiexams.com/faa/login and not found any of it on your list

Comment: The FAA does not identify if a PSI location administers FAA tests. I could only find a listing of the centers that are located outside the US. It is up to you to find out if you can take FAA written tests there. I am not entirely sure, but I think the FAA has cancelled all written tests outside the US except for US military personnel at some international bases.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for testing locations [here](https://faa.psiexams.com/faa/login). I tried searching a 300 mile radius around a few major cities and got zero results, so it seems that they are rare, if any exist at all. Still, you can search to see if there are any in your area.

The test itself only takes a couple hours, and doesn't need to be done until right before the checkride. So unless your time is *extremely* limited it shouldn't be too hard to squeeze it in.

Comment: Unfortunately, my time is extremely limited. I know this websites but as you can see, they list all countries in the world but most of them is empty. i just want to know if there is an intact list